# highcharts 5.0.14 issue with textOverflow

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart, axis-labels, ellipsis

After upgrading to Highcharts version 5.0.14, one of my bar chart with very long labels using `textOverflow: 'ellipsis'` is not working anymore. The whole chart is getting cut off on the right and there is so much white space on the left.

I tried removing following x-axis style config:
`textOverflow: 'ellipsis',`
`whiteSpace: 'nowrap'`, and then the chart renders fine. But I really need the ellipsis if the label text becomes too long and don't want it to wrap. So this is not my ideal solution.

See problem in jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1so3fezm/2/

I'm partly able to fix the problem by specifying a `width` for the x-axis labels along with the desired label ellipsis as:

`textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
width: 150`, but since my chart can be rendered with an option of varying widths, fixing the labels width is also fixing my chart width, which is not what I want. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have `xAxis.labels.useHTML: true`, but I'm not sure I see you using it? It seems like not setting it (or `false`) might avoid the problem?

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand I could never have figured this out! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has activated `xAxis.labels.useHTML: true` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML)). Removing `useHTML` or setting it to `false` appears to correct the issue without any further need for action, as you are not actively using the HTML feature.

See [this updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgd6fy2h/) of it in use.

Comment: Halvor Holsten Strand: you say "as you are not actively using the HTML feature" - looks like I need to learn something here about appropriate usage of configs. I thought useHTML would correctly render any special characters like an '&' in the label text, therefore used it, but my chart renders even without it !